# I can upload images and files on my website on desktop fine, but on mobile it doesnt work

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a separate gallery and file section. Both which work fine on desktop but not mobile.

Gallery code - just links to the invalid image page every time. Even when image should be ok to upload.

```
    //When upload button is pressed
if (isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    $image = date(U).$_FILES['image']['name'];
    $target = "gallery_images/".$username."/".$image;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `images` (username, image) VALUES ('$username', '$image')";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target);
    mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    //checking to see if uploaded file is actually an image
    $file_type = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($target));
    $allowed = array("image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/gif", "image/png", "image/svg+xml", "image/bmp", "video/x-flv". "video/mp4", "application/x-mpegURL", "video/MP2T", "video/3gpp", "video/quicktime", "video/x-msvideo", "video/x-ms-wmv");

    if(in_array($file_type, $allowed)){
        header("location:gallery.php");
    }else{
        header("location:invalid_file.php?img=$image");
    }
}
```

File Code - Uploads file name to db but doesn't actually put the file in the designated folder

```
    //When uploadfile is pressed - file is stored in db and folder
if (isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
    if($_FILES['file']['name'] == $row["file"]){
        header("location:file_copy.php");
    }else{
        $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $target = "file_storage/".$username."/".$file;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `files` (username, file) VALUES ('$username', '$file')";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target);
        mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        header("location:files.php"); 
        }
```

Comment: Any errors in your logs? Your code is weird though.  Why are you checking for file type after saving the file?. You can use php's finfo function to get the Mime type

Comment: @Akintunde Its written like that cause im an idiot who rushed it! thanks very much for pointing that out fixed it now. And thanks for your quick reply. Will take a look at error logs

Answer (score 1):

Compere this my correct code with yours.

```
<?php
$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","imgup");
if(isset($_POST['create_post'])){
    $post_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $post_image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "images/$post_image");
    $query = "INSERT INTO img(post_image) ";
    $query .= "VALUES('{$post_image}')";
    $create_post_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
}
?> 
<form action="fileup.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">       

        <label for="post_image">Post Image</label>
        <input type="file"  name="image">   
        <input type="submit" name="create_post" value="Publish">

</form>
```